# Hiding a button on a dialog box

Tags: dynamics-crm

How can I hide or disable the "Ignore and Save" button on the duplicate detection dialog box in Dynamics 365 CRM

I've tried to use a plug in but I experienced some errors. I also thought of checking the form for this dialog but can not figure out where it is stored in CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some parts of Dataverse are not customizable and duplicate detection dialog is one of such pieces. I'm afraid you won't be able to customize it.